# PHP 5.2.17: convert local time to GMT and GMT to local time

Tags: php

In my application, I just want to convert a local time to GMT and GMT to local time. I got the following two methods to do so.

```
function GmtTimeToLocalTime($date) {
    $gmt_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
    date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
    $timestamp_in_gmt = strtotime($gmt_time);
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
    $local_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp_in_gmt);
    //date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
    return $local_time;
}

function LocalTimeToGmtTime($date) {
    $local_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
    $timestamp_in_localtime = strtotime($local_time);
    date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
    $gmt_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp_in_localtime);
    //date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
    return $gmt_time;
}
```

But i got this date 1970-01-01  for all the inputs.

Please provide me the correct way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: for LocalTimeToGmtTime()-1969-12-31 12:03:32 as result

Comment: for GmtTimeToLocalTime()-1970-01-01 06:02:49 as result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps if you try with DateTime object you would get better result :

```
<?php
 function GmtTimeToLocalTime($time) {
    $date =  new DateTime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$time),new DateTimezone('UTC'));
    $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimezone('Asia/Calcutta'));
    return $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 }
```

Comment: $date = new DateTime::createFromFormat('U',$time,new DateTimeZone('UTC')); compile error - need $ symbol

Comment: Hum not need a $ but need to remove the "new", it's a typo

Comment: sorry, while i put the code in my project folder its not working

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat() in

Comment: wich version of php have you got? the spelling is correct so it can't be that.

Comment: I am using php version 5.2.17

Comment: I am using php version 5.2.17

Comment: that's the reason. createFromFormat is available since 5.3 (and I you know, now php is 5.4, upgrade is welcom)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16481/discussion-between-sridhar-and-artragis)

Answer (score 2):

A shortcut should be to look at [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php) and use `DateTime::setTimezone` to modify the timezone from GMT to local time, and vice-versa.

Edit: and of course, you can fill this DateTime with your timestamp using `DateTime::setTimestamp` or `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass latlong in following function to get timezone.

```
function getTimezoneGeo($latForGeo, $lngForGeo) {
        $json = file_get_contents("http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=".$latForGeo."&lng=".$lngForGeo."&username=demo");
        $data = json_decode($json);
        $tzone=$data->timezoneId;
        return $tzone;
    }
```